# Only highlight row in table with corresponding value of ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a html table 'TemplateData' populated dynamically from a db table...so for example could end up like:

```
ID  Name  Age
1   John  23
2   Mick  27
3   Mark  29
```

When the user clicks an image on screen it will post back the corresponding ID value. From here I want to change the background colour of the associating row.

So for example '2' has been posted back in 'fid'. so I have tried...

```
function highlightRowInTable(fid) {
    var dtable = $("#TemplateData");
    dtable.addClass("highlightedRow");
    }
```

However this highlightes the outer cells of the table. I only want to highlight the corresponding row.

Iv been messing around with parents and siblings but cant find any working examples on line...any ideas?

Comment: you want to highlight cell when corresponding cell is clicked right ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is selecting the entire table, and then applying a class to it, though it is hard to say for sure.  If you have an event listener attached to your table, you should be able to get the child  element that was clicked on and toggle its class.

```
document
  .getElementById('table')
  .addEventListener('click', function(event){
    // now event refers to the part of the dom that was clicked on
    console.log(event)
  });
```

Though I'm not sure without looking at your code.  if you already have listeners set up, you might need to give every row an id based on fid, so that your function could specify the id to add class to.

```
function highlightRowInTable(fid) {
    $(fid).addClass("highlightedRow");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you create your table you can add an attribute to your `<tr>` to help select it later when an image is clicked.

```
@foreach (var row in table)
{
   <tr data-uid="@row[id]">
       <td></td>
   </tr>
}

function highlightRowInTable(fid) {
    var rows = $('tr').filter('[data-uid="' + fid + '"]');
    rows.addClass("highlightedRow");
}
```